# how do i make my code read random lines 37 different times?

Tags: ruby

```
def pick_random_line
  chosen_line = nil
  File.foreach("id'sForCascade.txt").each_with_index do |line, id|
    chosen_line = line if rand < 1.0/(id+1)
  end
  return chosen_line
end`enter code here
```

Hey, i'm trying to make that code pick 37 different lines. So how would I do that i'm stuck and confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the same line to repeat more than once, I would do it in one line like this:

```
File.read("test.txt").split("\n").shuffle.first(37)
```

`File.read("test.txt")` reads the entire file.

`split("\n")` splits the file to lines based on the `\n` delimiter (I assume your file is textual and have lines separated by new line character).

`shuffle` is a very convenient method of `Array` that shuffles the lines randomly. You can read about it here:
http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle

Finally, `first(37)` gives you the first 37 lines out of the shuffled array. These are guaranteed to be random from the `shuffle` operation.

Comment: Thanks! but for some reason my script is giving me an error cause im trying to call the new line

Comment: @Tobias Weird. Can you try running `File.foreach("test.txt").to_a.shuffle.first(37)` instead?

Comment: i dont know let me try

Comment: C:/Users/EliLap/Documents/MyLib/lib/hackex/net/std.rb:38:in `Do': Not success: {
"success"=>false, "code"=>401} (HackEx::HackExError)

Comment: @Tobias 401 sounds like an authorization error. On which device are you coding this? Can you check your Ruby process has file read permission on the file?

Comment: im a begginer so how do i go about doing this? and i made the file myself

Comment: Assuming you are on Linux environment, can you do `ls -la test.txt` (or whatever the file name is) and paste here the result? I have to say this is very weird. `File.read(file_name)` should read the file with no issues. Maybe another process is locking the file. Are you able to open the file with your favorite text editor?

Comment: im on windows 7 and how do i do the 1s - 1a and the file name is id'sForCascade.txt

Comment: here is there a way i can send you my code so you can look at it?... i dont really want to take it public

Comment: I am not convinced you have a code problem. This error sounds to me like an environment issue due to file locks. Can you restart the computer, go into ruby console, and run the line I had sent you before?

Comment: it is a  code error because i ran your code alone and it worked but my code isnt displaying what it needs to can you help me fix it?

Comment: Ah. ok, so you may want to consider having this question closed - as we've addressed the question you asked. If you have a different issue we are happy to help, but I suggest you mark this question as closed (mark with a green check the answer that helped you resolve the issue) and start a new Stack Overflow question. Feel free to put in the comments the link to your new question and I'll take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704668/what-is-wrong-with-my-code-i-get-no-errors-but-its-not-doing-what-its-supposed

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Please consider marking the answer that helped you solve this question with the green check mark. This would add Stack Overflow reputation points to that person. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
input_lines = File.foreach("test.txt").map(&:to_s)
output_lines = []
37.times do
  output_lines << input_lines.delete_at(rand(input_lines.length))
end

puts output_lines
```

This will ensure that you aren't grabbing duplicate lines and you don't need to do any fancy checking.

However, if your file is less than 37 lines this may cause a problem, it also assumes that your file exists.

EDIT:

What is happening is the `rand` call is now changing the range on which it is called based on the size of the input lines. And since you are deleting at an index when you take the line out, the length shrinks and you do not risk duplicating lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save relatively few lines from a large file, reading the entire file into an array (and then randomly selecting lines) could be costly. It might be better to count the number of lines in the file, randomly select line offsets and then save the lines at those offsets to an  array. This approach is no more difficult to implement than the former one, but makes the method more robust, even if the files in the current application are not overly large.<sup>1</sup>

Suppose your filename were given by `FName`. Here are three ways to count the numbers of lines in the file:

*Count lines, literally*

```
 cnt = File.foreach(FName).reduce(0) { |c,_| c+1 }
```

*Use [$.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/globals_rdoc.html)*

```
 File.foreach(FName) {}
 cnt = $.
```

*On Unix-family computers, shell-out to the operating system*

```
 cnt = %x{wc -l #{FName}}.split.first.to_ii
```

The third option is very fast.

Random offsets (base `1`) for `n` lines to be saved could be computed as follows:

```
lines = (1..cnt).to_a.sample(n).sort
```

Saving the lines at those offsets to an array is straightforward; for example:

```
File.foreach(FName).with_object([]) do |line,a|
  if lines.first == $.
    a << line
    lines.shift
    break a if lines.empty?
  end
end
```

Note that `$. #=> 1` after the first line is first line is read, and `$.` is incremented by `1` after each successive line is read. (Hence base `1` for line offsets.)

<sup>1 Moreover, many programmers, not just Rubiests, are repelled by the idea of amassing large numbers of anything and then discarding all but a few.</sup>

Comment: I wrote this on a tablet where testing is a pain, so I didn't test. If you spot an error, please let me know.